# Why do escape characters in regex mismatch?

Tags: regex

1. If I want to match the dot symbol (`.`) I have to write this regex:

   `/\./`

Escape character is needed to match the symbol itself.

2. If I want to match the 'd' symbol I have to write this one:

   `/d/`

Escape character is **not** needed to match the symbol itself.

And if I want to match any character (`/./`) or any digit character (`/\d/`) it's vice versa.

It seems to me that this approach is not very consistent. What is the reasoning that stands behind it?

Thank you.

Comment: Actually, to match a dot, you need `/\./`, not `/\\./`.

Comment: Tim, thank you for the comment. You are totally right, I added an extra slash character because Stackoverflow preview showed no slash character at all. I'll edit the original post now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.` character is a reserved regular expression keyword. The `d` isn't. You need to include the escape character when you match a period to explicitly tell regex that you want to use the period as a normal matching character. `d` by itself isn't a reserved word, so you don't need to escape it, but `\d` is a reserved word.

I can see how, to someone coming to regex it can be a little odd, but the `.` is used so often, and I can't think of a time I've really needed to match periods it just makes more sense to have it be one character without the backslash.